# how to prove that there exists an extension of holomorphic functions on annulus

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:R_1<|z|<R_2\}$ and $f:A\to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function.Suppose there exist a sequence $\{p_n\}$ of polynomials such that $p_n \to f$ uniformly on every compact subsets of $A$.Show that $\exists$ a holomorphic function $g:B(0,R_2)$ such that g is an extension of f.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider a Laurent series for $f$, and show that the terms for negative powers of $z$ are $0$.

Comment: I got the point if terms for negative power is zero then what will be happened.But can you please tell me how terms of negative powers will be 0

Comment: Find the coefficients by a contour integral.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By the maximum modulus principle, $p_n$ converges uniformly on $|z|\leq r<R_2$.